# Convert date table into year in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi i'm having table curriculum_vitae with field named

```
    id int pk
    user_id int
    education_from  date            
    education_to    date.
```

it has **date** type and now i want to change it into years and with **year** type only by move it into new table like education_from_year and education_to_year. how can i accomplish this?

Comment: Presumably your current table would have more than one record per year.  How do you plan to handle this?

Comment: it has user_id and id of course.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen ok i'm adding those to field into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could avoid the conversion.

for a valid date  column in MySql you can  use the Year() for obtain the year value from your date

```
 select  year(education_from) , year(education_to )
 from your_table
```

and if you really need  a redundant value on the same row  you could use

```
update your_table
set my_year_col_education_from  = year(education_from), 
    my_year_col_education_to  = year(education_to)
```

Comment: and how can i move the data into new field in the same column. is it possible with just sql command?

Comment: answer  updated .. but you don't need  a conversion

Comment: perfect.  i will select your answer in 2  more minute.  thanks